# Hover эффект на блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я знаю, что в моём коде ошибка, но я не могу её найти. Как можно сделать, чтобы "1" выводил один раз, когда мы навели на .wrapper ? И когда убирали курсор с блока в консоль выводилось только одни раз "2" 
code : [click](https://codepen.io/kah3vich/pen/WNZwWQd?editors=1111)

```
$('body').on('mousemove', function() {
    if($('.wrapper').is(':hover')) {
        console.log('1')
    } else {
        console.log('2')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя слушатель стоит на `mousemove` т.е. при движении мыши многократно срабатывает скрипт. Попробуй слушатель `on mouseenter` и `on mouseleave`

UPD: добавил вариант с hover

```js
$(".wrapper").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        console.log(1)
    }, 
    mouseleave: function () {
        console.log(2)
    }
});

// И второй вариант с hover

//$( ".wrapper" ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
//function handlerIn(){
  //console.log(1)
//}
//function handlerOut(){
  //console.log(2)
//}
```

```css
.wrapper{
width 100px;
height:80px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'></div>
```